# Cast dynamic to Type list in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

New to dart here,

I was trying to convert the collection to a group by their names, and then taking those children values. Unfortunately I couldn't do that. The data comes from firestore collection, so not having issue with firestore.

So the category contains name as

```
            `: {name: 'Daily walk', Item:{......}}, {name: 'Evening walk', 
             Item:{.....}`

        var categoryListFiltered;

        categoryListFiltered = collection
                  .groupBy(categoryList, (Category element) {
                    return element.name;
                  })
                  .values
                  .cast()
                  .toList();
```

After the above code, I have separated them successfully but not it's children.
Meaning I cannot cast them to List.

I tried lot of ways more than 5 hours solve. but no way! Would someone please help me this out!

Thanks.

Comment: Where does `groupBy` come from?

Comment: If you could show us exactly how the object is right before calling the .cast().toList(). Because Im not as familiar to Firebase

Comment: groupby from collection package.

Comment: I have category model that holds another model.